# Need Emulator (240x400 and 360x640) j2me

Tags: java-me, emulation

I developed the game in j2me. I need emulator for screen 240x400 touch and 360x640 touch. Where should i get ?

Answer (score 1):

Download any of the manufacturers custom SDKs ([SonyEricsson](http://developer.sonyericsson.com/wportal/devworld/technology/other/java/sdk?cc=gb&lc=en), [Nokia](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Tools_and_downloads/), [LG](http://developer.lgmobile.com/lge.mdn.tnd.RetrieveTNDInfo.dev?modType=T&resourceNo=TND00000294), [Motorola](http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/tools/) )and find a device with your resolution

PS: It may be difficult as many of them moved to Android or other technologies